# Typeguard doesn't narrow type

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I'm creating an object to store a bunch of RGB colors, and nesting is allowed. So when looping through the object, I need to see which keys correspond to RGB values or to an object. However, every type guard I've tried won't actually narrow down the type.

```
type Color = [number, number, number] | 'transparent'
type ColorGroup = Record<string, Color>
type Colors = Record<string, Color | ColorGroup>

const colors: Colors = {
    black: [0, 0, 0],
    white: [255, 255, 255],
    transparent: 'transparent',
    primary: {
        '50': [211, 233, 252],
        '100': [179, 213, 248],
        '200': [127, 185, 251],
        '300': [68, 156, 253],
        '400': [0, 126, 254],
        '500': [13, 100, 226],
        '600': [17, 79, 189],
        '700': [15, 62, 157],
        '800': [10, 46, 122],
        '900': [1, 22, 77],
    }
}

const isColor = (color: Color | ColorGroup): color is Color => {
    return Array.isArray(color) || typeof color === 'string'
}

const usesColor = (color: Color):void => {
    // does something with the color
}

for(const color in colors) {
    if(isColor(colors[color])) usesColor(colors[color]) // error: type 'Record<string, Color>' is not assignable to type 'Color'
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=8&pln=32&pc=16#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJygXigbQHYFcC2ARhMgDRR5EnmXHIC6UAPlAOTDICG2AzmJ8gjZgrAFChIsRCgDiyOLjDooAJQgBjFABMAPDw4BLbAHNy8JMgB848NHMoeytZuS79yI6akXm32fMVrUU1eYChNCx4ALj9kRwwAb1EoFKhCBE51AGsYzAAGcgKoPPpSZNSAdwALA2AIXIAmAFYm8mbWqHbS8pSObj4BIWAY9i5efkFhVjLUqDAPfAEQGKTZ2dYmvNZGgEYdtoBmA7amhu611NYdvK3cnYB2AE42nePOgBYADnOLtgab7ZYHYNe7kHafDrNHY-C6sA4A3IANk+YKaiJOBxha1Y7wRWCKwPRnSa7yx602tyBb2uRQaDURZMuiLxmAe5CeYM+j0ZKVY9xZOw6iIaqPuPLYnwFRXeROBZxmv1YjwFbRFUHuYoVKQAvqJdcE4KEoAYePZUBgABQRFAxM2+M1yBRgACUMWtqBNsXQligq1SgmAuGQ2CgAEFkFwQAA6E3hyNW6TIZ3MFgSCBwABm4UT6DQGFY7k8Yn1IX0UFwPAgppzlvdtsTroAbnADFpvb6elAAPRdqBaOBVqA8OD4CDAGomKAVWpVKDj6DuvWiUQZlAJo3u40h908ZN+lIGDMWk1mhORTDu+jO5MVqunncXxNXvVAA)

Any ideas? Am I just missing something fundamental about type guards?

Comment: The type guard is fine.  The issue is with checking `colors[color]`.  If you assign the current color it to an intermediate variable and check that variable then it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've run into a design limitation in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33391](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33391) and [microsoft/TypeScript#31445](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31445) for more information.

The issue is that the compiler does not keep track of the results of property type guards unless those properties are a string literal or a number literal:

```
if (isColor(colors.black)) usesColor(colors.black); // okay
```

and *not* if it's a value stored in a variable:

```
if (isColor(colors[color])) usesColor(colors[color]) // error!
```

When accessing `colors[color]`, the compiler only knows that `color` is a variable of type `string`. After the type guard, you access `colors[color]` again, but the compiler doesn't realize that you checked it before because `color` is just some `string`-typed variable to it.  In some sense the compiler can't see the difference between your code and this:

```
declare const color1: string;
declare const color2: string;
if (isColor(colors[color1])) usesColor(colors[color2]); // error!
```

which would not be a good use of the type guard.

The above linked issues mention that while it would be nice if code like this were supported, it turns out to be very expensive in terms of compiler resources.  Keeping track of which *variables* are used as indices is a lot of extra and almost always unnecessary work.  The use case here is apparently not worth it... especially because:

---

There is a minor refactoring that gives the behavior you're looking for.  Instead of doing multiple indexing operations, do a single indexing operation and save it into its own variable, like this:

```
for (const color in colors) {
    const c = colors[color];
    if (isColor(c)) usesColor(c) // okay
}
```

Since `c` is its own variable, there's no longer any indexing-with-`string` to worry about.  The compiler can easily use the type guard on `c` to narrow the type of `c`.  So, you get the behavior you want, at the expense of slightly less idiomatic JavaScript.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJygXigbQHYFcC2ARhMgDRR5EnmXHIC6UAPlAOTDICG2AzmJ8gjZgrAFChIsRCgDiyOLjDooAJQgBjFABMAPDw4BLbAHNy8JMgB848NHMoeytZuS79yI6akXm32fMVrUU1eYChNCx4ALj9kRwwAb1EoFKhCBE51AGsYzAAGcgKoPPpSZNSAdwALA2AIXIAmAFYm8mbWqHbS8pSObj4BIWAY9i5efkFhVjLUqDAPfAEQGKTZ2dYmvNZGgEYdtoBmA7amhu611NYdvK3cnYB2AE42nePOgBYADnOLtgab7ZYHYNe7kHafDrNHY-C6sA4A3IANk+YKaiJOBxha1Y7wRWCKwPRnSa71KUB62M2tyBb2uRQaDURWPWiLxmAe5CeYM+j2Zl3ubJ2HURDVR9z5KVYn0FRXeROBZxmv1Yj0FbVFUHu4qVKQAvqJ9cE4KEoAYePZUBgABQRFAxC2+C1yBRgACUMVtqDNsXQligq1SgmAuGQ2CgAEFkFwQAA6M2R6M26TIV3MFgSCBwABm4WT6DQGFY7k8YkNIX0UFwPAg5rz1s99uT7qgADc4AYtL7-RSAPQ9qBaOA1qA8OD4CDAGomKAVWpVKCT6Ceg2iUQGHNWs0WpORGPpTJZV2pqs17eenh7jLZV0AbigfagcCynBAq60GgyglzJs9OxixZMG9RHfdRPyXY0K09Bp-0MQC1w3Ldkx3BxMF-egj0ratawsZC4lQ5MzlvVcsxQKAkx-PMjFzSJUwDFJyzCdRlHPfCLHoIDZnXMjEJw9QMJPbCUBtV0DSAA)